# How is the process done by detecting all the data on the page using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to make a progress bar that counts forward with the specified start date and end date line. I can perform the operation I want with the code I wrote. But since there is a lot of code, there is confusion.

I want to follow a more logical way. My current codes are listed below.

**MY HTML:**

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

**MY jQuery + PHP:**

```
progressBar(<?php echo strtotime("2020-02-20 10:00:00"); ?>, <?php echo strtotime("2020-02-20 15:00:00"); ?>, <?php echo time(); ?>, '#div1');
progressBar(<?php echo strtotime("2020-02-20 04:00:00"); ?>, <?php echo strtotime("2020-02-20 09:00:00"); ?>, <?php echo time(); ?>, '#div2');


/** Start Time, Stop Time, Now Time, Element Id **/
function progressBar(start, stop, now, element) {
    now++
    var timepast = now - start;
    var duration = stop - start;
    var percent  = ( 100 - ( timepast / duration ) *100 ).toFixed(2);

    $(element).text(percent);

    var timer = setTimeout(function(){ 
        progressBar(start, stop, now);
    }, 1000);

    if( percent < 0){
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}
```

**Desired Method/Result:**

I want it to automatically detect and count in real time all the elements that are set as follows.

I need jQuery (Javascript) codes to detect these HTML codes.

```
<div id="div1" data-start="2020-02-20 10:00:00" data-stop="2020-02-20 15:00:00"></div>
<div id="div2" data-start="2020-02-20 04:00:00" data-stop="2020-02-20 09:00:00"></div>
```

Comment: So you only need jQuery selectors to get these two elements?

Comment: I want to take the values in the elements with "data-start =" on the whole page and operate in the code I wrote.

Comment: Try with javascript setInterval function. i hope you help us.

Comment: Your code won't currently work with passing in more than one element.  Though the fix is relatively simple, have a read of: https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Comment: This line `progressBar(start, stop, now);` needs to be `progressBar(start, stop, now, element);`

Comment: Yes, I want to create "basic-plugin-creation".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the code below, you only have to create your `div's` and the script `automatically detect` them and shows the `progressbar`.

```js
function progressBar(start, stop, element) {

    var now = (new Date().getTime() / 1000);
    var timepast = now - start;
    var duration = stop - start;
    var percent  = ( 100 - ( timepast / duration ) *100 ).toFixed(2);

    $(element).text(percent);

    var timer = setTimeout(function(){
        progressBar(start, stop, element);
    }, 1000);

    if( percent < 0){
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}

$('div[data-start][data-stop]').each( function( index, element ) {
  var start = $(element).attr( 'data-start' );
  var stop = $(element).attr( 'data-stop' );
  progressBar( start, stop, element );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="div1" data-start="<?php echo strtotime("2020-02-20 10:00:00"); ?>" data-stop="<?php echo strtotime("2020-02-20 04:00:00"); ?>"></div>
<div id="div2" data-start="<?php echo strtotime("2020-02-20 04:00:00"); ?>" data-stop="<?php echo strtotime("2020-02-20 09:00:00"); ?>"></div>
```

Comment: That's exactly the code I want. Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

To find the matching divs, use:

```
 $("[data-start]")
```

and to extra the data-start/data-stop, use

```
$(this).data("start")
```

jquery attempts to type-coerce from .data(), so this should be enough, but you could wrap in `new Date()` to be sure

Giving an update to your existing code, add:

```
$(function() {
    $("[data-start")].each(function() { 
        progressBar(
            new Date($(this).data("start")), 
            new Date($(this).data("stop")), 
            new Date(), 
            this);
    });
});
```